# Check if a set is open or close or neither

Tags: real-analysis

I've got the set G = {$x\in R^2: |x| \le 2, |y-1| \gt 1$}

I need to determine whether this set is open or closed,
I've drawn the set and I think it is neither, but I'm not sure how to proof it.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I removed the proof verification tag because you didn't write any proof.

Comment: First of all, you must specify where it is open. If you are asking if your set, say $A$, is open in $\mathbb{R}$, then :Imagine balls around points on the boundary, i.e., the points on $ |x| = 2$. They intersect with $A$ as well as its complement. So, $A$ is not open. Now, do the same for complement of $A$, and you get it is not open either $\implies A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(2+\frac1n,3)\notin G$, but their limit point $(2,3)\in G$.

Note that $(0,-\frac1n)\in G$, but their limit point $(0,0)\notin G$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must specify where it is open. If you are asking if your set, say $A$, is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$, then :Imagine balls around points on the boundary, i.e., the points on $ |x| = 2$. They intersect with $A$ as well as its complement. So, $A$ is not open. Now, do the same for complement of $A$, and you get it is not open either $\implies A$ is not closed.